# I am not able to install some luaJIT dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, torch, luajit

I am trying to install the following  luaJIT dependencies in my Ubuntu 16.0.4
I try to do that by running the command below:

```
for NAME in dpnn nn optim optnet csvigo cutorch cunn fblualib torchx tds; do luarocks install $NAME;  done
```

The system challenges my permissions and gives me back the partial list of errors shown below:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory
‘/home/rkenaya/.cache/luarocks/https___raw.githubusercontent.com_torch_rocks_master’:
Permission denied mkdir: cannot create directory
‘/home/rkenaya/.cache/luarocks/https___raw.githubusercontent.com_torch_rocks_master’:
Permission denied mkdir: cannot create directory
‘/home/rkenaya/.cache/luarocks/https___raw.githubusercontent.com_torch_rocks_master’:
Permission denied Warning: Failed searching manifest: Failed creating
temporary cache directory
/home/rkenaya/.cache/luarocks/https___raw.githubusercontent.com_torch_rocks_master
mkdir: cannot create directory
‘/home/rkenaya/.cache/luarocks/https___raw.githubusercontent.com_rocks-moonscript-org_moonrocks-mirror_master’:
Permission denied mkdir: cannot create directory
‘/home/rkenaya/.cache/luarocks/https___raw.githubusercontent.com_rocks-moonscript-org_moonrocks-mirror_master’:
Permission denied mkdir: cannot create directory
‘/home/rkenaya/.cache/luarocks/https___raw.githubusercontent.com_rocks-moonscript-org_moonrocks-mirror_master’:
Permission denied Warning: Failed searching manifest: Failed creating
temporary cache directory
/home/rkenaya/.cache/luarocks/https___raw.githubusercontent.com_rocks-moonscript-org_moonrocks-mirror_master
```

I would highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Thank you Sam for your text editing. This would make my problem more readable.

Comment: Check the permissions of `~/.cache/luarocks`. Make sure you are the owner and have write permissions

Comment: Colonel Thirty Two:
Thank you for your suggestion. I will try that ASAP and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Colonel Thirty Two,

I have found a solution for the problem. In fact a sudo should prefix the command, but the problem is when you do it as below:

$ sudo for NAME in dpnn nn optim optnet csvigo cutorch cunn fblualib torchx tds; do luarocks install $NAME; done

it gives you an error.

The alternative is :
$ for NAME in dpnn nn optim optnet csvigo cutorch cunn fblualib torchx tds; do sudo luarocks install $NAME; done
and this should work for linux and os-x.

or you can also install the dependencies one by one as below:

sudo luarocks install dpnn
sudo luarocks install nn
..
..
..
sudo luarocks install tds